# Issue in mobile device in the ajax call remote option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In rails, I am using the same code to get js response and render UI according to the response . My code is like this

```
= link_to "Click here", :page=>(@page+1).to_s, :remote => true
```

But in the computer browser, it is generating js response while in mobile browser is generating html response

In computer it is getting the server log

```
 Processing by DemoController#list as js
```

While browsing in mobile it produces the log

```
Processing by DemoController#list as html
```

I want js reponse in mobile devise as well. What may be the issue? Please help me to solve . Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your js asset files for application.js and this controllers js.  In the past I have had issues where certain libraries cause issues with mobile and js

Comment: Its name is 'list.js.erb' file. Do we have to add it in conifg/initializers/assets.rb or app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Comment: I have two files list.html.haml and list.js.erb when I have given remote=true . In pc browser its invoking js file, but for mobile the html file is invoking